# Is the type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'double'

Tags: flutter

I am still learning flutter and I came throuygh a very weird error and still not getting why I have it. Here is my file

```
class _LocationScreenState extends State<LocationScreen> {
  WeatherModel weather = WeatherModel();
  int temperature;
  String weatherIcon;
  String cityName;
  String weatherMessage;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    updateUI(widget.locationWeather);
  }

  void updateUI(dynamic weatherData) {
    setState(() {
      if (weatherData == null) {
        temperature = 0;
        weatherIcon = 'Error';
        weatherMessage = 'Unable to get weather data';
        cityName = '';
        return;
      }
      double temp = weatherData['main']['temp'];
      temperature = temp.toInt();
      var condition = weatherData['weather'][0]['id'];
      weatherIcon = weather.getWeatherIcon(condition);
      weatherMessage = weather.getMessage(temperature);
      cityName = weatherData['name'];
    });
  }
```

The error is

> type int is not a subtype of type double

I would like to understand why I am getting this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error happens when you try to pass a value of type `int` into a variable of type `double`.

Dart does not automatically cast those types you have to handle it manually. So you have two options here:

- Change the variable type to `num` wich will cast the value automatically to `double` because both `int` and `double` extends from `num`.

```dart
num temperature;

temperature = 24; // works
temperature = 24.5; // also works
```

- Cast the value to `num`. Works because `num` is the super class of `double`.

```dart
int temperature;

temperature = 24.0 as num; // works

// does not work 
// temperature = 24.5 as int;
```

Answer (score 2):

As the error says

> type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'double'

that's because you're storing a data of type **int** in a variable of type **double** so try this code

```
double temp = weatherData['main']['temp'].toDouble();
```